# sed , awk or python in shell script

Tags: python

I have a shell script with the following line to remove double quotes " from a text file.

```
sed 's/\"//g' old_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

There is one more **awk** statement that selects only a specific columns from a ^ separated text file.

Both the statements are working as expected. But the server hangs when the input file is more than a few GB in size. I will like to know if **python** can do the same more efficiently.

update:

It is not stopping the server, but mysql hosted on the same server is slow when I run the shell script.

Comment: in depends from your realization!

Comment: Does your awk statement operate on `new_file.txt` or is it in a pipeline with your sed command?

Comment: sed output is not piped to awk. It operates directly on new_file.txt

Comment: Short answer, no, long answer, noooooooooooooooooooooooooo... You'll be making the same system calls at the end of the day.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier yes, if he avoids writing a giant intermediate file between the two commands.

Comment: @shantanuo: Do you need the intermediate output between `sed` and `awk`?

Comment: Yes. There are a few more processes between them. My boss asked me to consider php. But looking at what numpy can do, I do not think PHP is an option. Right?

Comment: @shantanuo: yes, PHP will actually be slower because it's not optimized. By 'more processes' you mean that the Python script will do a few more things on those lines? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @shantanuo: I've added a few possible solutions for the problem to my answer. But you should have explained this to us sooner.

Comment: This question is now inconsistent, does your boss want it to not impact the mysql performance? Have him pay for more server. Or use pipes. Or better define what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I wanted to know if the time and money invested in re-writing the script to python is worth it. and what others have experienced with similar use cases.

Comment: @shantanuo: Do you expect to run this script often? How often?

Comment: Once in a day. It takes several hours to complete if the file is too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that Python could do that faster. With a bit work, it could do the same thing with +/- same efficiency. Unless you attempt to do it wrong; because then it will be slower.

Both sed & awk operate in line mode. They are quite I/O-optimized, and I don't think you could improve over that. The Python script may be faster if it comes to performing operations but in this case it's *very unlikely* to be relevant.

Just pipe them like *@paxdiablo* suggests:

```
sed 's/"//g' old_file.txt | awk '...' > new_file.txt
```

Or, if the column format is simple enough, you can replace `awk` with simpler `cut` which would be faster:

```
sed 's/"//g' old_file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4 > new_file.txt
```

(example for columns 1, 2 & 4, space-separated)

And if you need the intermediate output, you can put `tee` in the pipeline to write it in the meantime:

```
sed 's/"//g' old_file.txt | tee inter_file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4 > new_file.txt
```

But it may be actually less efficient since both `inter_file.txt` and `new_file.txt` will be written at the same time.

---

Ok, now I think I understand what the problem is. Your problem is not that the script is not *fast enough* because it gets as fast as it can get. It's your hard drive which hits it throughput limit and thus other applications using it get delayed. You could say that it is simply too fast for you hard drive.

One solution is to try using `ionice` to give it lower priority. It may help, it may not make a difference at all.

```
ionice -c3 -p$$
```

gives the lowest (idle) I/O priority to the current shell or script. Similarly, you can start your script with given priority using:

```
ionice -c3 ./yourscript.sh
```

The results may vary upon I/O scheduler used. Some schedulers will ignore this, some may actually make the script slower (whenever mysql will be requesting I/O).

Alternatively, you could use an additional program which will limit the throughput going to sed, and effectively making it slower and giving some free space for mysql to fit in. You will, however, need to measure what throughput is optimal for you.

And finally, if none of the above is an option, you could jump in to Python, and add `time.sleep()` every few hundred or thousand lines to stop the script for a while to let mysql do its job.

Comment: "and I don't think you could improve over that" - you may want to rethink that :-) At a bare minimum, reading more data per call will always get you better performance simply because there's less function calls.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Do you really think it is likely that the time necessary to write the filter correctly gives so much gain it's even worth considering? I don't think you usually perform such operations on a few-gig files on a daily basis.

Comment: You only have to write the filter once, and I did it for you anyway so that would be zero times :-) Obviously the OP thought it important otherwise there wouldn't have been a question. In any event, it _clearly_ outstripped `sed`, it wasn't just a couple of percent, we're talking twice as fast. However, it's all moot since the question as it stands was not the question that was asked. I'll leave all that performance stuff in my answers as interesting but my contention is that scripts shouldn't be even running on a box where they'll affect "production-level" stuff.

Comment: The script needs to run on the same server because a) I use mysqldump to create the csv file b) it takes a lot of time to copy the big file to another aws server c) and it again affects the source server performance while doing scp d) cost

Comment: @shantanuo, you'll find you almost certainly use less grunt by copying the file off than be processing it somehow. Still, if you _must_ do it on the same emachine, simply nice and ionice the script.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely. Neither would be slurping the entire file into memory at one time so your limitations will basically be the disk I/O rate more than anything else.

I gather it's not *actually* hanging (stopping altogether), far more likely is that it's just taking some time to process bigger files.

A couple of things you can try.

First, if you're sending that `new_file.txt` file into the `awk` process, don't create an intermediate file at all. You should be able to do:

```
sed 's/\"//g' old_file.txt | awk 'some commands' >next_file.txt
```

Secondly, since it's a fairly simple substitution, you may find it's faster to write up your own fixed filter rather than rely on a `sed` or `python` script which may run slower because it has to cater to general cases.

In other words, something like:

```
create 1M buffer
read up to 1M from input
while not EOF:
    go through data removing `"` characters.
    write changed buffer to output.
    read up to 1M from input
```

The proper C code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
static char buff[1000000];
int main (void) {
    int sz;
    char *src, *dst;
    while ((sz = fread (buff, 1, sizeof(buff), stdin)) > 0) {
        src = dst = buff;
        while (sz-- >= 0) {
            if (*src == '"') {
                src++;
                continue;
            }
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
        sz = dst - buff;
        if (fwrite (buff, sz, 1, stdout) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error %d writing data\n", errno);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This *may* run faster due to the fact that it's for then specific case but, as with all optimisations, *measure, don't guess!*

On my system, compiling that code with `gcc -O3` gived the following results, first for `sed`:

```
pax> time ( cat Photo_* | sed 's/"//g' >/dev/null )
real  0m0.094s
user  0m0.080s
sys   0m0.024s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | sed 's/"//g' >/dev/null )
real  0m0.097s
user  0m0.076s
sys   0m0.032s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | sed 's/"//g' >/dev/null )
real  0m0.095s
user  0m0.092s
sys   0m0.012s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | sed 's/"//g' >/dev/null )
real  0m0.096s
user  0m0.060s
sys   0m0.048s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | sed 's/"//g' >/dev/null )
real  0m0.095s
user  0m0.088s
sys   0m0.016s
```

Then for the customised filter:

```
pax> time ( cat Photo_* | ./qq >/dev/null )
real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.012s
sys   0m0.028s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | ./qq >/dev/null )
real  0m0.032s
user  0m0.008s
sys   0m0.032s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | ./qq >/dev/null )
real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.012s
sys   0m0.028s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | ./qq >/dev/null )
real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.012s
sys   0m0.028s

pax> time ( cat Photo_* | ./qq >/dev/null )
real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.012s
sys   0m0.028s
```

So the average `system+user` and `wallclock` times are:

```
         system+user   wallclock
sed           0.1056      0.0954
custom        0.0400      0.0304
```

So it appears that a custom filter may well give you a performance advantage over the general case one. For test data, there are three files matching that wildcard, at sizes `3427158`, `5462472` and `5921534`, so a total of about 14M.

For a larger input size, using a single file of 3,791,657,984 bytes (about 4G), the `sed` (user + system) time was 27.037 seconds while the custom time was 9.020 seconds (both taking 5 samples and averaging).

---

And, as to your question edit, if this process is slowing down another, more important process, you should *not* be running it there. You should both `nice` *and* `ionice` a `copy/ftp/rcp` command which shifts the file off to a totally *separate* box where you can run scripts on it to your heart's content without damaging performance.

If I ran scripts on our production boxes that bought down their performance, I'd have half the site maintainers demanding my head on a plate :-)

Comment: It has been a good answer, and then you added the 'your own fixed filter'…

Comment: The answer still stands. Pipe it rather than creating a temp file so that most of the stuff happens in memory. Measure whether a custom filter works faster than the general case filter. If so, use the custom filter, if not, throw it away. But I have to say, I _have_ found improvements using this method.

Comment: @MichałGórny, you may want to check the update, a custom filter can _definitely_ outperform the general case one, by quite a bit.

Comment: The question was edited, and shantanuo actually seems to want the script to perform slower :P.

Comment: Also, could you give the benchmark results for a file which is `is more than a few GB in size`? :P

Comment: Sure, size = 3791657984 (~4G), sed user+sys = 27.037, custom = 9.020 (5 samples, averaged).

Comment: I meant one with comparison to the regular method. In wall clock. With real, non-sparse file. One where the disk I/O would prove that your method is at least noticeably faster. Otherwise, you're just *promising* the user that your method will be twice as fast while it wouldn't actually make a difference. And think that this user could cancel running `sed` to replace it with your method, believing it would be faster…

Comment: @MichałGórny, it's not entirely clear what you even _mean_ by "non-sparse", and wall clock is a bad measurement since it's affected by other stuff the machine may be doing. The disk IO for the runs was identical since it was the same input file, built from a large number of other files and a single 4G file pumped into both `sed` and custom filter. In any case, you have the code, you can profile it yourself with whatever data you consider more suitable. So can the OP, with their own data set. You should always profile on the likely input data, which is why my answer said measure, don't guess.

Comment: ah, sorry I mis-read the results. And as far as I know, user+sys is meaningless when the operation is highly I/O-bound.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely to be an improvement on your current approach, because you can perform both double quote removal and column selection at the same time and write out the final result. In this way you would avoid writing to disk a very large intermediate file. It could also be faster than putting sed and awk in a pipe, as that would require one extra process and some synchronization overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both `sed` and `awk`; just use `awk`.

Assuming you want the 3rd column:

```
awk -F'^' '{gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $3;}' huge_data_file
```

This has a number of advantages such as not requiring sed, a pipeline, an intermediate file etc. Also, the replacement of `"` is only done for the data contained in the required column, not for the whole line.

I tested this on a 2.1G file which contained 64,400,000 lines consisting of this data repeated (not sure if the data repetition taints my test):

```
"blah"^"blah blah"^"test1   ""^stuff
"blah"^"blah blah"^"test2   ""^stuff
"blah"^"blah blah"^"test3"^stuff
"blah"^"blah blah"^"test4^stuff^

$ time awk -F'^' '{gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $3;}' huge_data_file >/dev/null

real    2m31.706s
user    2m29.745s
sys 0m0.953s
```

No "hangs". Virtual memory usage did not exceed 105MB. Of course, actual performance may vary on your server.

---

**[EDIT]**

For comparison:

```
$ time sed -e 's/"//g' huge_data_file | awk -F'^' '{ print $3;}' >/dev/null

real    2m9.723s
user    3m34.355s
sys 0m3.585s
```

Which effectively torpedoes my "non-sed" solution, although it did require twice as much memory.